# Angular UI-Router: Multiple URLs to single state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have started using angular's ui-router, and I am trying to figure out how to have multiple URLS refer to a single state. For example:

```
/orgs/12354/overview
//retyrns the same pages as
/org/overview
```

My $state provider is currently set with something like this, and its unclear to my how to slip in the alias '/org/overview' route such that it properly inherits from the 'org' parent.

```
.state('org', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/orgs/:orgID',
  templateUrl: '/client/navigation/main.html'
})
.state('org.overview', {
  url: '/overview',
  templateUrl: '/client/overview/overview.html',
  controller: 'OverviewCtrl'

})
```

Answer (score 6):

This can be achieved using `when()`. Suppose this is the state you want to point to with multiple urls.

```
.state('app.home',
  {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'homeCtrl'
  })
```

In `config()` you can use `when()` as follows:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
   .config($urlRouterProvider){
       $urlRouterProvider.when(/homepage, ['$state','$match', function ($state, $match) {
          $state.go('app.home');
 }]);
}
```

Likewise you can add multiple urls pointing to same state.

Comment: This solution won't work if you want to have a URL like /orderOverview of a state 'orderOverview' and because of a different context you want to have another URL like /orderHistory which should point to the same state 'orderOverview' BUT keep the entered/used URL in your address bar.

Comment: Your solution would cause a changed URL.

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need to define substates without an url like below.

```
.state('org', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/orgs/:orgID',
  templateUrl: '/client/navigation/main.html'
})
.state('org.1', {
  templateUrl: '/client/overview/one.html',
  controller: 'OverviewCtrl'
})
.state('org.2', {
  templateUrl: '/client/overview/two.html',
  controller: 'OverviewCtrl'
})
.state('org.3', {
  templateUrl: '/client/overview/three.html',
  controller: 'OverviewCtrl'
})
```

Comment: how would this know that "/overview" was a valid route, since its not part of the /orgs path?

Comment: I haven't tested this, but you should be able to put the controller in the abstract state, because it's the same across all of the children, right?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, an abstract state doesn't return a view.

Also, since you're trying to use the plural `orgs` for the list view, and the singular `org` for the item view, you can't use appended routes, which is the default behavior.

```
.state('org', {
  url: '/orgs',
  templateUrl: '/client/navigation/main.html'
})
.state('org.overview', {
  url: '^/org/:orgID/overview'
  templateUrl: '/client/overview/overview.html',
  controller: 'OverviewCtrl'
})
```