# app state with optional param and no trailing slash

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
.state('tabs.map', {
    url:'/map/{location_id}',
    params: {
      location_id: { value: -1 }
    },
    views: {
      'map-tab':{
        templateUrl:'templates/map.html',
        controller:'MapCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

I've tried a number of different options for optional params that I've found on the web but none of them work exactly like I'm looking for. The code I've added allows for:

- ## /tab/map/.*?
- ## /tab/map/

but not

- ## /tab/map

I'm not sure why the trailing slash is causing a problem because [from what I've read](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/108#issuecomment-40558474) it shouldn't be a problem. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Recently Consulted

- [Angular UI-Router: Multiple URLs to single state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26416554/angular-ui-router-multiple-urls-to-single-state)
- [AngularJs UI router - one state with multiple URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28138169/angularjs-ui-router-one-state-with-multiple-urls)
- [Can angularjs routes have optional parameter values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510962/can-angularjs-routes-have-optional-parameter-values)
- [Laravel 4 Route issues with multiple and optional get params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140898/laravel-4-route-issues-with-multiple-and-optional-get-params)

## Solution

Introduction of **squash** to param variable

```
.state('tabs.map', {
    url:'/map/:location_id',
    params: {
      location_id: { value:null, squash:true }
    },
    views: {
      'map-tab':{
        templateUrl:'templates/map.html',
        controller:'MapCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use squash parameter to allow without trailing slash

```
  params: {
      location_id: {
        value: null,
        squash: true
      }
   }
```